# Memory Leak Observed in Erlang Application

Tags: memory-leaks, erlang, binary

Let me put my question as simple as below. Mine is a network router software built in erlang, but at a particular scenario I am observing very high memory growth as shown by VM.

I have one process which receives binary packet from some other process from socket.

This process, parses the binary packet and passes the binary packet to a gen_server (handle_cast is called)

The gen_server again stores some information in ETS table and send the packet to the peer server.

When the peer server responds back the entry from the ETS is deleted and the gen_server responds back to the first process

Also if the first process (which sent packet to gen_server) gets timedout after 5 seconds waiting for response from gen_server , it also deletes the ETS entry in the gen_server and exits.

Now I am observing high memory growth when lots of events gets timed out (due to unavailability of peer server) and from what i have researched its the "**binary**" and "**processes_used**" given by erlang:memory command thats using most of the memory.

but the same is not true when events are processed successfully.

Comment: so, it seems you have a bug when events get timed out. What's your question?

Comment: Memory growth obseved during Timeout's that is my question. Dont know why binary size is growing even though I am not storing binaries in any process . I just UDP send the events as soon as i receive them. Seems like reference counted binaries are getting copied which cannot be garbage collected...but why only on timeouts ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The memory lost can be basically only in three places:

1. The state of your gen_server

   - look at you state, find out if there is some big or growing stuff there
2. Your processes mailboxes

   - see to it that there is some way to always drain unmatched messages (for gen_server `handle_info` callback) in normal `receive`s a `Any ->`clause.
   - if the mailbox only fills up temporarily its probably because of the receiving process being too slow for the rate of messages produced.  This is usually a problem for asynchronous communication.  If its only temporary bursts that don't break anything this could be intended.

     - In this case you can either optimize the receiving process
     - or fix your protocol to use fewer messages
     - if you have multiple functions that receive some messages, make sure all receiving parts are being called regularly.  Dont forget the `Any ->` clauses.
   - Be aware that while you are processing in a gen_servers callback no messages will be received, so if you need more time in a callback that would be necessary asyncronous messages might pile up (e.g. random message arrival + fixed processing time builds a unbounded growing queue, for details see [Queueing theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory)
3. In your ETS table

   - maybe the information in the ETS is not be completely removed?  Forgot to remove something in certain cases?

Comment: Thanks..This explains a lot,as i was doing async communication using handle_cast. But as the memory was not getting freed up i am manually doing garbage collect when detected high timeouts.

Comment: All really good points. Also, since that gen_server is in the center of everything handling all messages sequentially, is there something you can do to further parallelize the activities? (Handling more in the receiving processes, spawn extra handling processes etc)

Answer (score 7):

trigger GC by hand and see what happens with memory.

```
[garbage_collect(Pid) || Pid <- processes()]
```

Comment: Thanks ..but this is what I have been doing till now. Just wanted to know why erlang not triggering it by itself

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you're leaving processes running that has references to binaries. If a process dies, all memory related to that process will be cleaned up (including any binaries that only belonged to that process).

If you still have leaking binaries, it means you have some long running process (server, singleton etc) that keeps references to binaries, either in its process state or by non-tail recursive functions. Make sure you clean up your state once process communication times out or they die. Also, check that you don't leave references to binaries on the heap by using non-tail recursive calls.

Comment: @Adam: Thanks. You are quite close to the the answer. It's the gen server that is showing lots of memory. Any idea how to clean up referenced binaries ?

Comment: @ArunMu: just stop referencing them in future states, e.g. by setting a field in your state vector record to undefined or even a new binary.

Comment: Just as an update,in my gen_servers mailbox i can see lot of messages and binary packets. The messages are those which the "First process" was sending to gen_server asking for the ETS table ID. Any Idea ?

Comment: @Peer: I am not maintaining any binary data in state.

Comment: @ArunMu: if you don't maintain lots of data in state then you can't have a normal memory leak: in a gen_server all that is kept is the state that is passed along.  Probably the memory are messages piling up in your mailbox(es).  The question here is why?  Two possible reasons: flooding or not receiving

Comment: Yes messages are piling up in mailbox and for "why?" question..event I dont know :P gen_serer should receive those messages as it is alive! or does it not receive those messages from processes who are already killed ??

Comment: Are you using gen_server:call/2 or just bang (!) when you communicate with your gen_server? Do you flush your mailbox on cases where it's needed, for example when stopping dealing with a client?